# Iteratively enumerating all permutations of $N$ objects using a generating set

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, permutations, group-theory

The group theory of $S_n$ shows that all permutations of $n$ objects can be generated from  the $n$-cycle $a:=(1 2 3 .. n)$ and the transposition $b:=(1 2)$.  (See Theorem 2.5 at https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/genset.pdf)

One can use this fact to label and enumerate permutations. For example, this shows such an enumeration for $S_3$ where the left hand side shows the action of the given element on $[0 1 2 3]$ and the right hand side shows a "labeling" representation in terms of $a$ and $b$:

```
0 1 2 3  () 
1 2 3 0  (a) 
2 3 0 1  (aa) 
3 0 1 2  (aaa) 
0 3 1 2  (aaab) 
3 1 2 0  (aaaba) 
1 2 0 3  (aaabaa) 
2 0 3 1  (aaabaaa) 
0 2 3 1  (aaabaaab) 
2 3 1 0  (aaabaaaba) 
3 1 0 2  (aaabaaabaa) 
1 0 2 3  (aaabaaabaaa) 
1 3 0 2  (aaabaaabaaab) 
3 0 2 1  (aaabaaabaaaba) 
0 2 1 3  (aaabaaabaaabaa) 
2 1 3 0  (aaabaaabaaabaaa) 
2 0 1 3  (aaabaaabaaabaaab) 
0 1 3 2  (aaabaaabaaabaaaba) 
1 3 2 0  (aaabaaabaaabaaabaa) 
3 2 0 1  (aaabaaabaaabaaabaaa) 
1 0 3 2  (aaabaaabaaabaaabaab) 
0 3 2 1  (aaabaaabaaabaaabaaba) 
3 2 1 0  (aaabaaabaaabaaabaabaa) 
2 1 0 3  (aaabaaabaaabaaabaabaaa)
```

Making this more precise, given any element $\sigma \in S_n$ and a generating set G we can find some positive integer $k$ and $d_i \in G$ for $ 1 \leq i \leq k$ such that $\sigma = \sum_{i=1}^{k} d_i$.

Let's say that a "labeling" is a map that sends every element $\sigma$ of $S_n$ to a specific choice of representation $d_{\sigma, 1}, ..., d_{\sigma, k_\sigma}$.

This observation leads to some interesting questions:

1. Is there a straightforward way to produce a labeling for $S_n$ given a generating set $G$?
2. Even better, can you produce a *minimal* labeling in the sense that no element could be represented by a shorter product of elements from the generating set?
3. Is there a correspondence between this method of generating permutations and the classical solutions like backtracking, "plain changes", or Heap's method, perhaps given some other set of generating elements rather than this specific choice of $a$ and $b$?  (See [https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/talks/perms.pdf](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Ers/talks/perms.pdf))  That is, does there exist a choice of generating set G and labeling L that would enumerate the elements in the same order as the other methods when the elements are sorted by label lexicographically?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @D.W. Took a pass at this, let me know if you still have concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to build up the [Cayley graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph) for $S_n$ with generating set $G$ iteratively, using breadth-first search to traverse the graph.  This will give you a labelling for every element of $S_n$, and moreover, because breadth-first search finds the shortest paths, it will also give you a minimal labelling.

I don't know whether there is any relationship to those other methods of enumerating permutations.

Comment: Interesting, thank you!  The idea to derive a minimal labeling from a BFS of the Cayley graph is great.  


Now I'm curious if you know any efficient way to generate the Cayley graph from a set of generators :)

One obvious brute force way would be to simply enumerate all products as: $a, b, aa, ab, ba, bb, aaa, aab, .. $ etc until you reach $N!$ distinct elements.  

But I think this would involve some unnecessary computations to collapse multiple representations of the same element like (e.g. bb = aaaa).

Comment: I seem to have found a comment in this [lecture](http://tinyurl.com/yckzfkrw) (top of page 7) that might imply it's a difficult problem in general, but would love any pointers to something more specific: 


> This is the computationally “difficult” part of this algorithm. In
> general, finding the Cayley graph, or even more simply determining whether two
> arbitrary words in a presented graph are equal, is an undecidable problem: it is
> provable that no algorithm exists that will always solve this problem

Comment: @JaredStewart, yes, generate the Cayley graph by doing BFS starting from a fixed node (the identity permutation).  Note that given any node you can easily find the edges out of it, and thus you have everything you need to build up the graph on the fly, using BFS to do so.  It is easy to do; the only problem is that the graph has $n!$ nodes so takes $n!$ space to represent and $n! \times |G|$ steps of computation to build.

Comment: Let me try to show you what I mean about avoiding unnecessary complications.

Looking at the Cayley [graph](https://tinyurl.com/3srku457) of $S_4$

You always know that if the previous arrow to a vertex was green, you won't reach a new element from the edge produced by applying the green element again to that vertex (this is basically the relation $b^2=1$).  Is there any general way to avoid unnecessary edges based on the relations of the elements in the generating set?

Comment: One more interesting question this raises to me: Given a set of generators G, we can find a minimal labelling in the manner you describe above.  Call the sum the length of the minimal labels over all elements of the group the "labelling length" of that generating set.  

Is the labelling length independent of the choice of generators?

Comment: @JaredStewart, that last question sounds like a question to pose on Math.SE.

Comment: For posterity, the latter question is answered by Terrence Tao [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/07/10/cayley-graphs-and-the-geometry-of-groups/).

He gives two generating sets for the cyclic group $Z_6$ that have Cayley graphs with differing numbers of edges.